# curl exception 60: Certificate Security api exception

Tags: security, curl, ssl-certificate, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught CurlException: 60: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates thrown in **/home/ldr/public_html/src/base_facebook.php** on line **886**
>
> See: http://ldr.x10.bz/examples/with_js_sdk.php

I've been getting this error for 2 days now and can't find any information on where it has come from? Why is the certificate known and is there a way for it to be unknown again?

It had been working for months previously, so not sure if the API has just updated but I've deleted everything and just uploaded the PHP SDK 3.1.1 but still no luck :(

I've read about disabling the peer verification but sounds like a bad idea (plus I know it works with it enabled). Probably accidentally unchecked a box somewhere- any ideas on how to restore it back to normal would be very appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Almost forgot: welcome to stackoverflow Liam!

Comment: Thanks! I haven't got enough reputation to vote up yet apparently - but it'll come!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates are verified against a truststore somewhere on your system. This truststore should be updated once in a while; e.g. Firefox and Windows do this when updating the software. The error is a bit unclear; it actually means your curl client gets a certificate for which it does *not* have a trusted (root) certificate.

You may want to visit that site with your favorite up to date browser and save the root certificate somewhere, then create a CA store with that single certificate in it. Of course it will fail if that one gets replaced or if the server chooses another certificate authority.

Possibly updating curl or the OpenSSL library may do the trick, try that first :).

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand the error now ! Thanks

Okay, so I added the certificate to the list SSL certificates in cPanel but this hasn't changed anything? It's a shared server so I can't update the software I don't think. If I just sit it out for a few weeks will it update itself?

Thanks for your help! Liam

Comment: It might do yes. Maybe ask the administrator otherwise, it should be a relatively simple operation.